# Is there a proper way to forward to an sfDoctrineRoute without losing the current request?

Tags: php, redirect, symfony1, doctrine, forward

I'd like to forward (or redirect) to an sfDoctrineRoute without losing the current request data.

My issue is that when I use forward, the route isn't executed correctly and so things like $form->getObject() don't work.  But if I redirect to the URL, I lose all my request data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not pass the request params with the redirect?

```
$this->redirect('@someroute?params='.$params);
```

Comment: I don't like using string concatenation to pass parameters around... Anything better managed?

Comment: @Omega: Haven't found anything. I'd also like an array somewhere in there to pass parameters in, would be cleaner.